# Gnome 3.6.1 doesn't work with startx anymore, only with gdm

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gdm

I normally prefer my system to boot in text mode and manually start Gnome with startx but if I do that with Gnome 3.6.1, I get many errors and a basically unusable operating system. After installing gdm however, Gnome works perfectly fine again. Why is that and how can I return to my startx?

Detailed explanation:

I use archlinux and after a system update this morning (2012-11-1) with `pacman -Syu` which upgraded my Gnome to 3.6.1 I could not successfully boot Gnome 3 anymore. The graphical user interface was there but there was an error message like "There was an error, all extensions are deactivated" and I could not focus windows other then the first one created and the window title bars at the top were not there anymore.
I changed my .xinitrc from `ck-launch-session gnome-session` to `exec gnome-session` because I've read somewhere that this is necessary now but I got exactly the same error. Only after installing gdm and I think enabling it with `systemctl enable gdm` does Gnome work correctly again.

Comment: I don't Know about archlinux, but the debians have a Set of scripts in /etc/X11/xsession.d/ which construct the command to Start your Desktop Environment. You could Peak in there to See how gdm launches Gnome 3 and steal that command.

Comment: OP, is this question still a problem for you? if so, you should give an error log, not just a description.

Comment: @strugee: Sorry, I did just use gdm from that point on and changed my pc, so that I cannot reproduce the error log and cannot verify the answers but I will mark the one from jason as I guess it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a display manager and you do want systemd/logind to correctly activate your session, you need to endure that you start `X` in the same TTY that you login on.

See [troubleshooting session permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions) on the Arch Wiki for the details, but essentially it means ensuring you source the correct `xinit` scripts in your `.xinitrc` and you start `X` with:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

As [the wiki notes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login), you can replace the `-eq 1` comparison with one like `-le 3` (for vt1 to vt3) if you want to use graphical logins on more than one VT.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 startx -- vt0
```

See also [this Unix.SE question regarding startx and Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50622/using-startx-on-fedora-17-a-non-root-user-cannot-join-new-wireless-networks/52160#52160).